# Are there rules to create Troops of casters?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, house-rules, homebrew

So a person I play Pathfinder with showed me the [Troops sub-type](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#subtype-troop) which opens up a whole lot of possibilities for high level parties to deal with high numbers of enemies.

But I don't find much about how to deal with [Troops](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/troop/) composed of caster characters.

Let's say that a high level party (lvl 15) is attacking an evil wizard school, and they could end up fighting through dozens of low level wizards.

Of course a GM could always just add 20 level 4 wizards to the mix, but honestly, it would be TERRIBLE to manage that combat for the GM, it would take days for the players to act again, and rolling all those possible saves and ranged touch attacks would be just not fun at all. And that's not even mentioning that a 4th-6th level wizard would probably not be able to do much to a 15th level character unless the player rolled a 1 on their saves, and that has 5% chance of happening.

So I think the immediate solution would be to implement something like a Troop of wizards.

Are there any rules or guidelines for such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I don't know any specific rules

But, there are potential cases for caster Troops, or more specifically, Troops that have casters' support. The Ruins of Azlant AP presents a troop creature,

> Ulat-Kini Troops CR10 (Beyond the Veiled Path, p9)

Specifically (from the noted creature)

> **Dispelling (Sp)** Once per round as a free action that
>   does not provoke attacks of opportunity, an [...]
>   troop can attempt to dispel a magical effect within
>   200 feet as per dispel magic. This represents sorcerers
>   embedded within the troop formation who are
>   attempting to overcome enemy magical effects. The
>   [...] troop has an effective caster level of 10 for
>   this purpose. An [...] troop can use this ability up to
>   10 times per day.

From this, it seems reasonable that a Troop that would have spellcasters could have a (limited per day use) ability to cast spells. CR 10 it could be any 3rd level spell. The bounds of this power are up to you.

---

Troops are not a great way to represent powerful spellcasting. Any creature that would be described as 'powerful' should not be summarized into a Troop because the nature of Troops is a collective of weaker units uniting to become a greater threat.